# Polymorphism determination issue

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, dispatch

I have a problem I am working on.  I have a number classes which inherit each other in this pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <list>

class TimeObject
{
  public:
    virtual void Tick()=0;

    std::list<TimeObject*> ticks;
};

class MapObject : public TimeObject
{
  public:
    MapObject()
    {
        ticks.push_front(this);

        printf("Create MapObject %p\n", this);
    }

    void Tick() { printf("mapobject tick\n"); }
};

class ControlObject : public MapObject
{
  public:
    ControlObject()
    {
        ticks.push_front(this);

        printf("Create ControlObject %p\n", this);
    }

    void Tick() { printf("controlobject tick\n"); }
};

int main()
{
    ControlObject test;

    std::list<TimeObject*>::iterator it = test.ticks.begin();

    for(; it != test.ticks.end(); it++)
    {
        TimeObject *trigger = *it;

        trigger->Tick();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The list in the example stores any `TimeObject` derived class.  My problem is that when storing `MapObject` pointers in the list that are also `ControlObjects` dispatch always picks the `ControlObject` function.

Is it possible to trigger the `MapObject` function with a `ControlObject` pointer using polymorphism?  If it isn't possible/pratical, what would be a good alternative?

Comment: Good alternative would be to design your code according to the C++'s polymorphism feature instead of trying otherwise.

Comment: I know. That is exactly why I asked what would be a better alternative instead of trying to force the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ***always*** store pointer to the Base class `A*` in the list(`std::list< A*>`).
The pointer should be correctly made to point either a object of type `B`or `C` ***before*** you add the pointer to the container.
Once you do that, dynamic dispatch will take care of calling the *correct* function for you depending on the actual object type. You don't need to do anything.

I don't know why you want to have any design which is otherwise, If you have any good reasons to do so please let know of them.

**Why it always calls `ControlObject::tick()` in your code?**
When you call:

```
ticks.push_front(this);
```

in `ControlObject::ControlObject()` you basically end up overwriting the first pointer you added to the list, The type of the first pushed pointer is not `MapObject *` anymore it is `ControlObject *` because you changed the pointer behind its back.You did not transfer ownership of the pointer to the  list but you both had shared ownership and you modified the object in your list through the constructor call in derived class. This leaves you with two `ControlObject *` objects in the list which dynamic dispatch correctly determines and calls the correct method.

There is nothing wrong in what dynamic dispatch does, it is the correct behavior.
If you want to call `MapObject::Tick();` then you will explicitly have to tell the compiler to do so, dynamic dispatch works on the actual type of object and it is working correctly.

```
void controlobject::Tick() 
{ 
    printf("controlobject tick\n"); 
    MapObject::Tick();
}
```

---

Replicating from the comments:

> I am afraid this is a bad design.The code works as it should,it works as defined by the C++ standard.The problem lies in the design.And unless you provide the details of what you are trying to achieve in a broader sense it is difficult and rather pointless to speculate on a new design.

Comment: The problem is that the dispatch always picks C even if I want to call B, then C on the same object.

Comment: @ShawnB: Can you please post a small compilable code sample that reproduces the problem? A code sample is best to demonstrate a problem rather than words, I fear We are both seeing different things based on the wordy problem definition.

Comment: if all objects are C, then no matter what the pointer is, the object will still be C and therefor the dispatch will correctly pick C not B.

Comment: It has to be an oversight in my actual code, the parts of actual code I used to create an example worked as I intended.

Comment: @ShawnB: :) That is the reason of trying to provide a simplistic compilable code sample, more often than not One is able to spot oversight problems with a small sample.

Comment: The sample was wrong, here is the edited version that properly shows the problem.

Comment: My issue is that ControlObject::Tick shouldn't always call MapObject::Tick, the only correct order would be in the list.  How can I change my program to behave properly?

Comment: @ShawnB: I am afraid this is a bad design.The code works as it should,it works as defined by the C++ standard.The problem lies in the design.And unless you provide the details of what you are trying to achieve in a broader sense it is difficult and rather pointless to speculate on a new design.

Comment: I thought it might happen like that. If you put that in I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: @ShawnB: Done! [SPACE FILLER]

Answer (score 0):

Using a cast on the variable of type C to the type B should do the trick.

```
   C c;
   B b;
   c.Function();
   ((B)c).Function();
   A * l[] = {&c,&b,&c};
   l[0]->Function();
   l[1]->Function();
   l[2]->Function();

   B test = *(B*)l[0];
   test.Function();
```

Comment: It would, but I don't what type of object I'm working with during the function call.

Answer (score 0):

In your current example you should be able to call both virtual members (or just the one depending on the underlying type) by calling `MapObject::Tick()` inside `ControlObject::Tick()`:

```
class ControlObject : public MapObject
{
  public:
    ControlObject()
    {
        ticks.push_front(this);

        printf("Create ControlObject %p\n", this);
    }

    void Tick() { printf("controlobject tick\n"); MapObject::Tick(); }
};
```

The explicit function call notation is required.